# my regex for finding words start with e not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

hi i am using tihs code to find words start with e but it is`t work

### code

```
import re
a="bitte gebe eine nummer bein:"
result=re.sub(r"(\s(e).*\s$)","lol",a,count=1)
print(result)
```

### the output i expect

```
bitte gebe lol nummer bein
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$` matches the end of the string/line in regex ([Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-2)).  Your regex would only match a word starting with `e` that happens to have a space after it and the end of the string right after (for example `"eins zwei eine "` would work).

In addition, `.*` is greedy and will consume the rest of your string.
You will also need to put spaces around your replacement string for the desired output.
So you want something like this:

```
import re

a = "bitte gebe eine nummer bein:"
result = re.sub(r"(\s(e)\w+\s)", " lol ", a, count=1)
print(result)
```

`\w+` will match `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` as many as times as possible and will stop at a space to avoid consuming the rest of the string.

Comment: its not procuding the right output, can you write some explaining code to elaborate?

Comment: This will still remove all the words except the last, and fail to find a word which isn't preceded by a whitespace character.

Comment: its wrong givs me `bitte gebelolbein:`

Comment: Updated my answer to produce the expected output as given in the question.

Comment: @tripleee I missed it consuming everything, good catch. If the asker wants to match words at the start and end I will update my answer.

Comment: The simple solution would be `\be\w*\b`

Comment: @tripleee I didn't want to change their original pattern too significantly, should I have done so?

Comment: The question is unclear so my recommendation would be to simply not attempt to answer it.

Comment: Fair enough, will keep that in mind